# ReSharper unit tests pending indefinetely

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, resharper

first of all, I've never used unit tests with ReSharper before, so I don't know how to debug it.  The problem is that if run MS unit tests by VS test explorer everything works fine, but if I run it through resharper's Unit Test Sessions it just does nothing and stays in a pending state, even with just one test starting with Assert.Fail. I am seeing no load on CPU or anything.

I am using ReSharper 8.0.14.856 with Visual Studio 11.0.50727.1 . Searches bring me many results with older versions, but I guess those should work fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see you use VS2012 RTM, but according to http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/index.html -> "System requirements", you need to have at least Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 (there were some changes in MSTest API between RTM and Update 3, ReSharper 8 supports the latest ones). So, please install Update 3 to your VS2012 installation and you will be able to run MSTest tests.